# Powershell Excel - Using new range for search gives errors for old range

Tags: vba, excel, powershell

I am a complete beginner to Microsoft PowerShell, but I have worked with C++, Java, and C#. I was working on this small script for my job, and I came across a strange issue that is likely due to me not properly understanding how ranges work. This script is supposed to open up an Excel workbook, search each sheet for a name, and give the names that match along with their information. The problem is when I set the range again to search for the starting column index of information (in this case, the column to the right of the column labeled "Description"), it breaks the range when it searches for more than one match of the same last name.

I have a do-while loop that uses worksheet.range.entirerow.findnext() so that I can find multiple with the same last name. This works until I used a new range, worksheet.range.entirecolumn.find(). This is my latest code of what I tried, but I have already tried hardcoding $Range to 5 (which worked, but I want it to be dynamic) or used a new variable $RowRange (which didn't fix the issue). If I understood correctly, the range is like the current selection of two or more cells, so why can I not reset it or use a new variable? It does not loop, so I only keep finding the first name in each sheet.

P.S. As a side question, I had an issue of shutting down the process of this excel document I want to open in the background without shutting down other Excel workbooks. For some reason, using Get-Process EXCEL | Stop-Process -Force; shuts down ALL of my open workbooks. I commented it out, but I'm worried about the process not quite ending when it's done executing this code.

```
# Prepare output file for results
$FileName = "TEST";
$OutputFile = "Results.txt";
Remove-Item $OutputFile;
New-Item $OutputFile -ItemType file;
$Writer = [System.IO.StreamWriter] $OutputFile;
Clear-Host
Write-Host Starting...

# Start up Excel
$Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application;
$File = $FileName + ".xlsx";

# Prompt user for last name of person to search for (and write to the Results.txt output file)
Clear-Host
Write-Host Search for users in each region by their last name.
$SearchLastName = Read-Host -Prompt "Please input the person's last name";
Write-Host Searching for person...;
$Writer.WriteLine("Name Search: " + $SearchLastName);
$Writer.WriteLine("");

# Then open it without it being made visible to the user
$Excel.Visible = $false;
$Excel.DisplayAlerts = $true;
$Excel.Workbooks.Open($File);

# For each worksheet, or tab, search for the name in the first column (last names)
$Excel.Worksheets | ForEach-Object{
    $_.activate();
    $Range = $_.Range("A1").EntireColumn;

    # Note: To search for text in the ENTIRETY of a cell, need to use the find method's lookat 
    # parameter (use 1). Otherwise, if searching for Smith, Nesmith also gets detected.
    $SearchLast = $Range.find($SearchLastName,[Type]::Missing,[Type]::Missing,1);

    $Writer.WriteLine($_.name + ": ");
    if ($SearchLast -ne $null) {
        $FirstRow = $SearchLast.Row;
        do {
            # If a first name was found, get the first name too
            $FirstName = $_.Cells.Item($SearchLast.Row, $SearchLast.Column + 1).value();

            # Then display in proper order
            $Writer.WriteLine(" " + $SearchLast.value() + "," + $FirstName);

            # From here, find the relevant information on that person
            # Search for the column labeled "Description", the starting column is the next one, ending column is the number of used columns
            $BeginCol = $_.Range("A1").EntireRow.find("Description",[Type]::Missing,[Type]::Missing,1).Column + 1;
            $MaxColumns = $_.UsedRange.Columns.Count;

            # Check each column for relevant information. If there are no extra rows after "Description" just skip
            for ($i = $BeginCol; $i -le $MaxColumns; $i++) {
                # The information of the current cell, found by the row of the name and the current row
                $CurrentCell = $_.Cells.Item($SearchLast.Row, $i);

                # Only add the description if it exists.
                if (!([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($CurrentCell.value2))) {
                    $Description = $_.Cells.Item(1,$i).text();
                    # Concatenate the description with it's information.
                    $Display = "  - (" + $Description + ": " + $CurrentCell.text() + ")";

                    # Display the information
                    $Writer.WriteLine($Display);
                }
            }

            $Writer.WriteLine("");

            # Keep searching that name in the current workbook until it finds no more
            $SearchLast = $Range.FindNext($SearchLast);

        } while (($SearchLast -ne $null) -and ($SearchLast.Row -ne $FirstRow));
    } else {
        $Writer.WriteLine("Not Found");
    }

    $Writer.WriteLine("");
};

# Cleaning up the environment

$Writer.close();
$Excel.Workbooks.Item($FileName).close();

$Excel.Quit();

# Force quit the Excel process after quitting
# Get-Process EXCEL | Stop-Process -Force;

# Then remove the $Excel com object to ready it for garbage collection
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Excel);

# Then, open up the Results.txt file
Invoke-Item Results.txt;
```